# How to change start page in PhoneGap 1.x

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova

I am trying to update the web files for a PhoneGap project by having it download an update package and overwrite the www files for the PhoneGap project. The problem is that the www files appear to be stored in the bundle and not in the documents directory. I can copy these files out to the documents directory on launch, but I am still unaware of how to tell PhoneGap to use the index.html file from the documents directory instead of the original www directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by overriding `+(NSString*)wwwFolderName` and `+ (NSString*) pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath` I believe that by overriding `+ (NSString*) pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath` I may run into some problems with other parts of PhoneGap.

```
+(NSString*)wwwFolderName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/www",[super applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
}
+ (NSString*) pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath
{
    NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSMutableArray *directoryParts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[resourcepath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
    NSString       *filename       = [directoryParts lastObject];
    [directoryParts removeLastObject];

    NSString* directoryPartsJoined =[directoryParts componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
    NSString* directoryStr = [self wwwFolderName];

    if ([directoryPartsJoined length] > 0) {
        directoryStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self wwwFolderName], [directoryParts componentsJoinedByString:@"/"]];
    }
    if (![[self wwwFolderName] isEqualToString:@"www"]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[self wwwFolderName],[self startPage]];
    }

    return [mainBundle pathForResource:filename
                                ofType:@""
                           inDirectory:directoryStr];
}
```