# How to set a web page as PhoneGap startPage?

Tags: ios, cordova

I began to learn PhoneGap recently in iOS platform, and I encountered a problem. How can I change the `startPage`?
I set `startPage` as follows:

```
self.viewController.startPage = @"http://www.google.com";
```

It did not work, and I also tried the following way:

```
 NSURLRequest *request =       
  [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[URL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

It also did not work.

I do not know how to do this. Is there anyone can help me out?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you want this in the app store, doing this will almost certainly mean instant rejection.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advise! Any idea to solve my problem???

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for my application. 
Create a local index.html page as phonegap expects it.
Inside html, set `window.location` to whatever page you need it to go to.

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script> window.location.href='http://www.google.com' </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1 class='loading'> Loading </h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note: Make sure you put the `http://` in the location otherwise it may consider as relative link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
......
......
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
//variables…..
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   PGView.StartPageUri = new Uri(“www.google.com“, UriKind.Relative); 
   .....
   .....
}
```

Check [How to change start page in PhoneGap 1.x**strong text**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086145/how-to-change-start-page-in-phonegap-1-x)

Comment: Thanks, My environment is IOS not android, any ideas in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can put starting point of application in `plist` file.